# Double image background on canvas not sharing the same size

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to make a section on a website have two background images that will reveal the bottom one as the pointer moves across the screen.

I'm still new to javascript, and my code is made up of bits and pieces that I've found on google, but I can't seem to get the top image to share the same resolution and image size for whatever reason as the bottom image.

Here is the link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/Awktopus/pen/zYwKOKO

And here is my code:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="main-canvas" id="canvas-size" class="background-size"></canvas>

<image src="https://i.imgur.com/PbGAAIy.jpg" id="upper-image" class="hidden-bg"></img>

<image src="https://i.imgur.com/Gx14sKW.jpg" id="lower-image" class="hidden-bg"></img>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden-bg {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var can = document.getElementById('main-canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
can.width  = window.innerWidth;
can.height  = window.innerWidth / 2;
var upperImg = document.getElementById("upper-image");
var lowerImg = document.getElementById("lower-image");
var pat = ctx.createPattern(upperImg, "no-repeat");
var canvas = ctx.canvas ;
var hRatio = canvas.width  / lowerImg.width    ;
var vRatio =  canvas.height / lowerImg.height  ;
   var ratio  = Math.max ( hRatio, vRatio );
   var centerShift_x = ( canvas.width - lowerImg.width*ratio ) / 2;
   var centerShift_y = ( canvas.height - lowerImg.height*ratio ) / 2;


can.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var mouse = getMouse(e, can);
    redraw(mouse);
}, false);


function redraw(mouse) {
    can.width = can.width;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(lowerImg, 0,0, lowerImg.width, lowerImg.height, centerShift_x,centerShift_y,lowerImg.width*ratio, lowerImg.height*ratio);  
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,can.width,can.height);
    ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, 250, 0, Math.PI*2, true)
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.fillStyle = pat;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, lowerImg.width, lowerImg.height, centerShift_x, centerShift_y, lowerImg.width*ratio, lowerImg.height*ratio);
}

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    redraw({x: -500, y:-500})
}

function getMouse(e, canvas) {
    var element = canvas,
        offsetX = 0,
        offsetY = 0,
        mx, my;

if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
        do {
            offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
            offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
    }

    mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
    my = e.pageY - offsetY;

    return {
        x: mx,
        y: my
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this right you will want to set the width and height and draw the upper image using `drawImage()`. Just use the same ratios as the lowerImage. No need to use `createPattern` for this.

codepen: https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/BaRLoxX

```js
var can = document.getElementById('main-canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
can.width  = window.innerWidth;
can.height  = window.innerWidth / 2;
var upperImg = document.getElementById("upper-image");
var lowerImg = document.getElementById("lower-image");
//var pat = ctx.createPattern(upperImg, "no-repeat");
var canvas = ctx.canvas ;
var hRatio = canvas.width  / lowerImg.width    ;
var vRatio =  canvas.height / lowerImg.height  ;
   var ratio  = Math.max ( hRatio, vRatio );
   var centerShift_x = ( canvas.width - lowerImg.width*ratio ) / 2;
   var centerShift_y = ( canvas.height - lowerImg.height*ratio ) / 2;


can.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var mouse = getMouse(e, can);
    redraw(mouse);
}, false);


function redraw(mouse) {
    can.width = can.width;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(lowerImg, 0,0, lowerImg.width, lowerImg.height, centerShift_x,centerShift_y,lowerImg.width*ratio, lowerImg.height*ratio);
  
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,can.width,can.height);
    ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, 250, 0, Math.PI*2, true)
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(upperImg, 0,0, lowerImg.width, lowerImg.height, centerShift_x,centerShift_y,lowerImg.width*ratio, lowerImg.height*ratio);
}

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    redraw({x: -500, y:-500})
}

function getMouse(e, canvas) {
    var element = canvas,
        offsetX = 0,
        offsetY = 0,
        mx, my;

if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
        do {
            offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
            offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
    }

    mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
    my = e.pageY - offsetY;

    return {
        x: mx,
        y: my
    };
}
```

```css
.hidden-bg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="main-canvas" id="canvas-size" class="background-size"></canvas>

<image src="https://i.imgur.com/PbGAAIy.jpg" id="upper-image" class="hidden-bg"></img>

<image src="https://i.imgur.com/Gx14sKW.jpg" id="lower-image" class="hidden-bg"></img>
```